# They do it in Silicon Valley

Tags: riddle

They do it in Silicon Valley

If you move things around

If you lived in the desert

For a month you could as well

You might ignore me

But I am still important

Comment: Maybe a time for hint since it has been a lot of days since you posted this puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> Starvation,

because

> When a process isn't getting cpu time it's called starvation.

> In the desert there is less food. You can starve for a month and not die.

Comment: Interesting but not the answer I had in mind

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Fragmentation

If you move things around

> Files are stored in different parts of the drive

If you lived in the desert

> Fragmentation causes desertification

For a month you could as well

> Large silicon valley companies can allow fragmentation to continue up to a month maybe

But I am still important

> Defragmentation is important for speed

Comment: More important and for everyone

Comment: Sorry I did not understand Defrag should be done by everyone you are saying?

Comment: It is not a tech word